# Email template: locale lang in url

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email-templates, locale

As suggest the title; what I want to do is to set url in my email template different depending on locale language.

What I tried to do:

> config path='web/unsecure/base_url'}}{{config
>   path='general/locale/code'}}/generic-url-key

to get something like **mysite.net/en/generic-url-key** or **mysite.net/fr/generic-url-key**

The problem is that the variable:

> {{configpath='general/locale/code'}}

return something like en_EN, fr_FR and I can't this value in my url

Is possible to set my own variable in database that return me something like "en", "fr"? How does magento will return me the value depending on locale lang?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use Customer Account URL:

> {{var this.getUrl($store, 'customer/account/')}}

and set url-key per language on the back office